# What survival model can handle a different time for each covariate?

Tags: survival, time-varying-covariate, unevenly-spaced-time-series

I would like to fit something like a Cox model but each covariate on my data could have been measured at a different time, different for each person.

Is there any alternative survival model allowing to use simultaneously different times for each covariate?

[image]

For example John could have had a flu in 2010, a stroke in 2012, I know his weight in 2014. Mary and Sam could have information from different periods. And with this information I want to create a model to know if he is likely to die in 2016.

Answer (score 1):

It's certainly possible to have covariate values that change with time in a Cox survival model. The counting-process data format specifies a start time, a stop time, and an event indicator for the time period when an individual has a defined set of covariate values. Those time periods can differ from individual to individual. Such data can be fit by a Cox model. See the [time dependence vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/survival/vignettes/timedep.pdf) of the R `survival`.

It's also possible to develop a joint model of covariates over time and of survival based on those covariate values. The R [Survival Task View](https://cran.r-project.org/view=Survival) has links to some implementations.

*A few warnings*

Provided that an individual can have at most 1 event, the counting-process format can allow an individual to be removed from analysis during time periods when there are no data available, and returned to analysis during other time periods. For any time period included in analysis for an individual, however, you must have values for *all* modeled covariates on the data row for that individual and time period. If you are missing some values, you might be able to use multiple imputation.

Don't forget that Cox models are based on *instantaneous* values of covariates in place for all at-risk individuals at each event time. For example, do you think that having flu in 2010 will *always thereafter* affect the hazard of death in the same way? Or might the association of flu with hazard of death decline over time after the flu? If the latter, then you need to have a way to provide some time-adjusted variable that represents the association of flu with outcome. The needs to be done not only for that individual's own event time, but also for all event times when that individual is at risk for an event and thus included in the calculations.

One of the most important decisions in survival analysis is the choice of the reference for `time = 0`. Setting `time =0` at birth is certainly one such choice, but it's not always appropriate. For example, clinical studies often set `time =0` to some clinical event time (having a stroke, diagnosis with cancer) and use age at that clinical event as a covariate. Be careful in your choice.